# What does this mean: a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}$ has at most $n$ solutions over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

What does this fact mean:

> "the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_{i}x^{i}$ has at most $n$ solutions over $\mathbb{Z}_{p} $" ?

Thanks in advance,

Yaron.

Answer (score 3):

Fix a prime $p$ and integer $n\geq 1$. Let
$$f(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots +a_0$$
be a polynomial with integer coefficients $a_j\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose at least one of $a_j$'s to be coprime to $p$.

Now consider the congruence
$$f(x)\equiv 0\ (\operatorname{Mod} p)$$
An integer $a$ is a solution of the congruence iff
$$f(a)\equiv 0\ (\operatorname{Mod} p)$$
meaning iff $p$ divides $f(a)$. But this is equivalent to say
$$[f(a)]_p=[0]_p$$
this last equation taking place in the field of integers modulo $p:\mathbb{Z}_p$. You can easily check that
$$[f(a)]_p=f([a]_p)$$
hence the assertion: "the congruence $f(x)\equiv 0\ (\operatorname{Mod} p)$ has at most $n$ solutions modulo $p$" means that you can find at most $n$ classes of integers modulo $p$, call them: $[x_1]_p,[x_2]_p,\ldots,[x_n]_p$ such that
$$f([x_j]_p)=[0]_p$$
for every $j=1,2,\ldots,n$

If you don't assume that some $a_j$'s is coprime to $p$ than your congruence could be the trivial one, having infinitely many solutions.

Comment: can you please expand your explanation?

Comment: i got the idea of replacing each $a_{i}$ with the class it represents, but i didn't get the last part.

Comment: @user76508 i tried to rewrite answer

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you mean "the polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ has at most $n$ solutions over $\mathbb{Z}_p$," which means there are at most $n$ different elements $\alpha\in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\alpha^i = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it means that the equation $\sum_0^na_ix^i=0$ has at most $n$ solutions when viewed as an equation over the field of $p$ elements, ${\bf Z}_p$.